# How to get the feature names on the shap plot from an XGBoost Model?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, xgboost, shap

I have a dataset with a text column ("description"), 2 categorical columns ("type" and "action") and a binary variable ("score").

```
y = project['score']
X = project(['type', 'action','description'], axis=1)
```

After processing the 'description' field (removing accents, punctuation, stop words, and stemming), I am vectorizing it with TfidfVectorizer and creating a sparse matrix.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, max_features=50) 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1, 2)) 
y = project["score"].values.astype(np.float32) 
X = sp.sparse.hstack((vectorizer.fit_transform(project.description), project[['type','action']].values), dtype=float, format='csr') 
X_columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
```

Then, I split into training and test.

```
train, test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
```

After that, I create an XGBoost model to predict the project score (0,1):

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=42) 
xgb_model.fit(train, y_train) y_pred_xgb = xgb_model.predict_proba(test)[:, 1] 
xgb_performance = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_xgb)
```

Later, I am trying to plot the SHAP graph:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(xgb_model) 
shap_values = explainer(test) 
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=test, feature_names=X_columns)
```

I need shap to show me the feature names on the plot, instead of the number of the features, as it is showing now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCla6.png)

Here is some sample data:

| description | type | action | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tecnolog cinacalcet indicaca hiperparatireoid | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| tecnolog medic gefitinib iress indicaca linh | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| tecnolog citogene hibridizaca situ fluorescenc | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| tecnolog paricalcitol zempl indicaca trat prev | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| tecnolog canaquinumab ilaril indicaca sindrom | 0 | 2 | 1 |

I have already tried feature_names=X_columns, but I get an error "index 77810 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 77810".

Answer (score -1):

Your `X_columns` is only the column names from the vectorizer, but you've added back on the two columns `["type", "action"]`; append those names to the end of the `X_columns` array.

Comment: I have tried to add the columns with:

```
X_columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
X_columns=np.expand_dims(X_columns, axis=-1)
X_add= np.array(project[['type','action']].columns.tolist())
X_columns = X_columns + X_add
```
And I get the same error "index 77810 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 77810"

Also I have tried to add those columns by doing:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=teste, feature_names=X_columns["type", "action"]) 
```
and it didn`t work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I can check later, but `expand_dims` doesn't seem useful. I think `hstack` or `vstack` should be fine?